Unable to get Manage External Storage permission
In this Document Scanner App, I accessed the storage photos and import to my app as well, But I also want to Write External Storage to create a folder in External Storage where I can Store the documents. Only a single permission dialogue box appears which asks for the permission to access photos, the other one which is about Allow User to Manage Storage, does not appears.
I tried to get Read and Write External Storage (Manage External Storage), I can read the storage but Unable to Manage it for creating a folder in Local Storage. Without Manage External Storage the app crashes while saving the document. I also tried to get permissions manually in app info settings and it works well. But It is required to get permissions from app for a user.
@Composable
fun setupScanner() {
    val options = GmsDocumentScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setGalleryImportAllowed(true)
        .setResultFormats(RESULT_FORMAT_JPEG, RESULT_FORMAT_PDF)
        .setScannerMode(SCANNER_MODE_FULL)
        .build()
    val scanner = GmsDocumentScanning.getClient(options)

    Text(text = "Welcome to ScanWush")

    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    ) {
        var imageUris by remember {
            mutableStateOf<List<Uri>>(emptyList())
        }
        val scannerLauncher =
            rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
                onResult = {
                    if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        val result =
                            GmsDocumentScanningResult.fromActivityResultIntent(it.data)
                        imageUris = result?.pages?.map { it.imageUri } ?: emptyList()
                        result?.pdf.let { pdf ->
                            val docName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                            val folderName = "ScanWush"
                            val folder =
                                File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderName)
                            if (!folder.exists()) {
                                folder.mkdir()
                            }
                            val file = File(folder, "$docName.pdf")
                            val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
                            pdf?.let { it1 ->
                                contentResolver.openInputStream(it1.uri)?.use {
                                    it.copyTo(fos)
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        this,
                                        "Saved to ScanWush Folder",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            AsyncImage(
                model = imageUris,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)) // Add some space between the image and the button

            Text(text = "Welcome to ScanWush")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)) // Add some space between the image and the button
            Button(onClick = {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        arrayOf(
                            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        ),
                        1,
                    )
                } else {
                    scanner.getStartScanIntent(this@MainActivity).addOnSuccessListener {
                        scannerLauncher.launch(
                            IntentSenderRequest.Builder(it).build()
                        )
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            it.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            }, modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)) {
                Text(text = ("Scan PDF"))
            }
        }
    }
}


Can you post code of onRequestPermissionsResult also share crash log

MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not a dangerous permission, so you cannot request it at runtime. You can launch an activity to request the permission.
Note that your app will not be allowed to be distributed on the Play Store unless you justify your use of this permission. That will be difficult to justify. Please consider using the Storage Access Framework instead, such as ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree.
